# Terraform on GCP fails to create pubsub topic stating permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Created a service user to manage terraform under the project and gave it `roles/owner`. Created the key for this terraform user.

Terraform code is simple:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "my_topic" {
  name    = "my_topic"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}
```

just creating a pub-sub topic.

`terraform plan` works but terraform apply gives me:

> google_pubsub_topic.my_topic: googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action., forbidden

I have even tried giving the service account `roles/pubsub.admin` not sure I understand what's going on because my service account has the owner role associated with it yet it can't create a pubsub topic.

Can anybody help me figure this out please?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit (to expand on my comment about what worked)**: 
I had created the service account using gcloud.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create terraform \
  --display-name "Terraform admin account"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding myproject-182220 \
 --member serviceAccount:terraform@myproject-182220.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
 --role roles/owner

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create terraform-admin.json \
 --iam-account terraform@myproject-182220.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

To continue my debugging, I created a new service account using the console / GUI  --> API & Services --> Credentials --> Create Credentials --> Service Account Key --> New Service Account  (With the owner role).  With this new service key json file, I was able to run my terraform code without a problem.

Now my confusion is, why did this work but not when I used gcloud to create a service account and give it the same role?

Comment: Can you run `gcloud` to create this topic? I think you will get same error. Double check if you get the right permission.

Comment: i have no issues running gcloud with my user account and creating the topic.  I'm not sure how I can use gcloud with a service account credentials.  I could obviously use the service account in python or something to create the pubsub and see if i get the same errors.  My user account also has "owner" role on the project, same as the service account

Comment: I tried creating other resources with the same service-account with the owner role, and I still get permission denied.  I'm not sure what I need to do to create a service-account that I can use to create resources with terraform.

Comment: my service account was created with gcloud cli and then the roles/owner bound to the account also using the same gcloud cli.  In addition, I also got the key using the cli.  Just to test, I created an account from the Api & Services menu -> credentails -> create new key and service account.  Using the newly created account from the cli, everything works as expected.

Comment: correction to the above comment: newly created account from the *ui*

Comment: Adding a comment to this because I saw some activity in Google Community with regards to the same query posted there:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-dev/5MI-v4Bsknk/discussion
Hopefully someone in similar situation can be helped by the activity on the thread above.

Comment: To anyone who's seeing this now, I'm running into a problem where the `google_pubsub_topic` is being created in a DIFFERENT project than what the `project` key refers to. I haven't been able to find a solution so far

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable the pub/sub api via google cloud or it might be possible using terraform.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the service account did have the authorization and the api was enabled.  This is a really old question that didn't really get me any answer and doing it from the UI had solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

The sample usage configuration for the Google provider looks more like:

```
// Configure the Google Cloud provider
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("account.json")}"
  project     = "my-gce-project"
  region      = "us-central1"
}

// Create a new instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  # ...
}
```

This can be read in more detail on the "Google Cloud Provider" documentation [page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html) from Terraform.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.